# Google Maps not loading on hidden divs

Tags: jquery, css

I need to have two maps each being displayed in css tab format. The problem I have is the second 'hidden' map does not seem to load resulting in it appearing in the left top corner of the tab area.

Is there a way I can ammend my code so that both maps load or at least loads when the tab is clicked.
[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/xzer6/1/)

Comment: both maps loads for me..

Comment: Yes both do load however the second one does not initialize, the marker is not in place.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you will need to include the maps API and trigger the `resize` (and possibly `setCenter`) events upon switching tabs.

Comment: Have you googled this behaviour? I guess no. That is a well known problem and there are workarounds. Just google it and you find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering the `visibility` instead of the `display` CSS attribute makes sure the maps are getting attached to the DOM and are rendered on load (while the second is not displayed) which leads to expected behavior.

I adjusted your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/73hZa/

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome throws an error in console.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://jsfiddle.net/xzer6/1/ from frame with URL http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?
```

Here on stackoverflow are some questions about that issue, but afaik no solutions. I haven't found a solution for that either.

Google Maps seems to try to access the parent frame (your page), which is not allowed. The only workarround is using the Google Maps API.